# Strapi w. Docker-compose - how do I create a config/server to attach Strapi to a url?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, strapi

I hope one of you can help me.

I have a website running Strapi in Docker as Backend. I use Nginx as a server. For now, I have used it with the original URL, but I want to run it over HTTPS with an upstream URL like dashboard.website.com.

My problem is that I don’t know how to create the server.js file to tell Strapi that it should allow another URL instead of the standard one. There are many guides but none showing how to create it with docker-compose.

Can one of you explain how I can create the server.js file for Strapi and make Strapi aware of it when I run Docker-compose?

**Here is a copy of my docker-compose.yml file:**

```
version: '3'

services:
  nodejs:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: nodejs
    container_name: nodejs
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - app-network

  webserver:
    image: nginx:stable-perl
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - web-root:/var/www/html
      - ./server/nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - nodejs
    networks:
      - app-network

  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    container_name: certbot
    volumes:
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
      - web-root:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html --email [EMAIL ADDRESS] --agree-tos --no-eff-email --force-renewal -d [DOMAIN]

  strapi:
    container_name: strapi
    image: strapi/strapi:3.6-alpine
    environment:
      - APP_NAME=strapi-app
      - DATABASE_CLIENT=mongo
      - DATABASE_HOST=db
      - DATABASE_PORT=27017
      - DATABASE_NAME=strapi
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=
      - AUTHENTICATION_DATABASE=strapi
    ports:
      - 1337:1337
    volumes:
      - strapi-app:/srv/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - app-network

  db:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo:4.4.5-bionic
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=strapi
    volumes:     
      - dbdata:/data/db
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  dbdata:
  node_modules:
  certbot-etc:
  certbot-var:
  strapi-app:
  web-root:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /
      o: bind
```

**And here is a copy of my nginx configuration:**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        access_log off;
        server_name [DOMAIN];

        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
                allow all;
                root /var/www/html;
        }

        if ($http_user_agent ~ (LieBaoFast|UCBrowser|MQQBrowser|Mb2345Browser) ) { 
                return 403;
        }

        location / { return 301 https://[DOMAIN].org$request_uri; }
}

upstream dashboard {
    server strapi:1337;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name [DOMAINN];
        access_log off;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/[DOMAIN]/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/[DOMAIN]/privkey.pem;

        if ($http_user_agent ~ (LieBaoFast|UCBrowser|MQQBrowser|Mb2345Browser) ) { 
                return 403;
        }

        # WEBSITE
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://nodejs:8081;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        # STRAPI - ADMIN
        location /d {
                #rewrite ^/d/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
                proxy_pass http://dashboard;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
                proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        }
}
```

Comment: strapi doesn't care about the url. You only need to ensure your nginx reverse proxy to your strap hostname:port (e.g. `proxy_pass http://localhost:1337`) or if you are using docker-compose service u use e.g. `proxy_pass http://strapiServiceName:1337`

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial - Thank you for your answer, I already tried that, and i even tried with upstream as well, but it doesn't seem to work no matter how i set it up. When i do it like you suggest I get 502 from Nginx. I was researching a bit and it seems like they require upstream and the url in configure/server.js (For strapi) to be configured.

Comment: what did you see in your nginx log? There's no url configuration, there's only a host and port configuration. If it's a 502 bad gateway, nginx logs will tell you what is it. I have to let you know, while running a nodejs application, your domain/hostname doesn't matter. Show your docker-compose.yml and your nginx if you truly wants help. Else will end up guessing, which is a waste of time.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial - I have added my docker-compose.yml and nginx.conf file in the question. I hope that can help you. Sorry that my question was missing important information, it went a bit fast when i wrote it. Unfortunately i didn't look in my nginx log, because i forgot about it.

Comment: for most part it looks okay. are you able to access the strapi app from the nginx container using curl?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes I can access with curl. I have tried to change the upstream to the docker-compose name “strapi”, since that is what the container is called. I have managed to get it up and running, but it seems like strapi doesn’t know what to do with the url. If I access /d/admin I get “Not found” in the browser, and when I look in the log from Strapi it tried to find something with url /d/admin. I don’t think strapi knows that /d/admin should lead to the admin dashboard.

Comment: I have updated my nginx configuration above to match what I have tried today. As mentioned, when I go to /d/admin I get “Not found” and I can see in the strapi log it tries to find something but it doesn’t interpret it as going to the admin dashboard

Comment: According to [strapi docs](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/admin-customization.html#deploy-the-entire-project-on-the-same-server) by default admin panel is accessible thorough `/dashboard`. As you have commented out `rewrite` command from nginx config, have you tried updating `config/server.js` according to the docs? If so it would be good to add its content to the original question.